# List of lpeg usage in ConTeXt

Tags: context

`luatex` comes with `lpeg`, a powerful pattern matching library. A quick `grep` (`rgrep --color "lpeg" /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/context/*`) shows that ConTeXt mkiv makes an intensive usage of it.

As a non ConTeXt user, the code is not that easy to understand. I'd like to have a list of all lpeg applications in ConTeXt and, when possible, a way to reuse part of the code with LaTeX (no need to reinvent the wheel, lpeg grammars can sometimes be cumbersome).

Comment: This question is better suited for the ConTeXt mailing list.  On TeX.SX questions should be specific.

Comment: @HenriMenke I don't understand what you mean by 'specific'. My question can be answered as a list of `lpeg` applications, possibly with filenames where code is available and a short description of the parser / grammar. I can ask an other question to know how to reuse part of ConTeXt code in LaTeX, but is it necessary? My feeling is that my question has a wider scope than ConTeXt.

Comment: The reuse in LaTeX part should definitely be an own question because this heavily depends on the intended use-case.  Basically it should be quite straightforward to reuse the parsers once you strip out all the ConTeXt specific stuff (mostly members of the `context` table).  Related info can be found in the [Garden](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/LPeg).

Comment: A lot of specialized LPEG parsers can be found in [`base/mkiv/l-lpeg.lua`](https://bitbucket.org/phg/context-mirror/src/beta/tex/context/base/mkiv/l-lpeg.lua).  On first sight they only involve pure LPEG routines and should thus be reusable in LaTeX as-is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LPEG parsers are used extensively in ConTeXt. The simplest ones to port to LaTeX (or perhaps use with a light wrapper) and those used for modules. Here are some of the example:

- `m-chart.lua` for parsing flowchart instructions
- `m-database.lua`for parsing CSV
- `m-escrito.lua` for parsing postscript
- `m-markdown.lua` for parsing markdown
- `m-spreadsheet.lua` for parsing spreadsheet instructions (a la Excel)
- `x-asciimath.lua` for parsing asciimath markup
- `x-calcmath.lua` for parsing calcmath markup
- `x-mathml.lua` for parsing mathml

Comment: Great: exactly what I was looking for (+1). May I ask you to add some examples of syntax and results? I guess that l-lpeg.lua is the core file where common patterns are defined?